# Reading from .csv file giving me a vector, not a dataframe?

Tags: r, csv

I am very new to R and am struggling to import data from a .csv file.

Specifically, I am trying to pull 31 responses, some "1", some "2", some "3", and some "4" from the .csv file. This data is under the header Q21

So I tried doing:

```
c <- mydata["Q21"] #because (mydata$21) gave an "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors response
```

But that just returned 
[1] NA

I am looking for 31 integer responses.

No idea what I'm doing wrong. Would truly appreciate any and all help as I get on my feet with this language.

EDIT:

str(mydata) yields
chr "/Users/charles/Documents/Work/Survey/CSV/Acme_Company.csv"

I did use read.csv(mydata) and it produced everything, it seemed to have column headings like Q20.

When I typed in c <- mydata$Q21 (that was a typo I wrote before), I got:
Error in mydata$Q21 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

> mydata[1:3,]
>   Error in mydata[1:3, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
>
> is.data.frame(mydata)
>   [1] FALSE
>
> colnames(mydata)
>   NULL
>
> mydata[, "Q21"]
>   Error in mydata[, "Q21"] : incorrect number of dimensions

So I don't know-- mydata isn't a data frame, right? So what should I do if I want to use the information in it?

Comment: **Post a reproducible example. Use `dput()`.** Just show us a few lines of your dataframe, say `mydata[1:3,]`.

Comment: How did you import your data? It doesn't sound like `mydata` is a data.frame. Did you use `read.csv()` or something?

Comment: Show us `str(mydata)` . Also check `is.data.frame(mydata)`, sounds like it's false, so your `read.csv()` (or whatever command you used) didn't return you a dataframe - please post the read command.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `mydata` is not a dataframe but a vector; so `read.csv()` didn't return you a dataframe. (Post the command you used to read the data, then post the output of `str(mydata)` ).

> (mydata$21) gave an "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors response

---

That's your error, you meant `mydata$Q21`. `mydata$21` is attempting to access a column named `21` not `Q21`. Read your error messages more closely ;-)

> mydata["Q21"] just returned [1] NA

First, check if `mydata` actually has a column called `Q21` or not. Show us `colnames(mydata)`.

Second, to get a slice of a column, you need `mydata[, "Q21"]` , you absolutely need the leading comma, which signifies that the thing after the comma is column names or indices.

Comment: I don't think the error message suggests that the column name is an issue, as normally that would return `NULL` (although not for $21 which would be a different error if $"21" wasn't used). It seems to just suggest that `mydata` is a vector, matrix or something.

Comment: @ping well I thought of suggesting that mydata might not be a dataframe and that `read.csv()` didn't return OP a dataframe, but a vector. But I thought I'd give them the benefit of the doubt.