# Why is read.csv() giving me a list from a .csv file instead of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

One [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945704/reading-from-csv-file-giving-me-a-vector-not-a-dataframe) did have a similar type of issue but it looks like there were some typos involved and it wasn't using the right functions, it was unknown that it wasn't a data frame. Mine is being read in as a list from a table structured .csv file. I've also attempted the rbind option in do.call suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/convert-a-list-to-a-data-frame) but that didn't work so it's commented out, it still showed up as a list under typeof().

Here's a public **[Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h_b-dB2WjKDSDm2X_75koGOmudES6nukwUU5ilONkoA/edit?usp=sharing)** of the dataset and here's my reproduceable code:

```
# Read study file
getwd()
bank <- read.csv("attemptCSV.csv")
bank
typeof(bank)
bank <- data.frame(bank)
typeof(bank)
colnames(bank)
#do.call(rbind.data.frame, bank)
#typeof(bank)

#> typeof(bank)
#[1] "list"
#> bank <- data.frame(bank)
#> typeof(bank)
#[1] "list"
#> colnames(bank)
# [1] "age"       "job"       "marital"   "education" "default"   "balance"   "housing"   "loan"     
# [9] "contact"   "day"       "month"     "duration"  "campaign"  "pdays"     "previous"  #"poutcome" 
#[17] "y"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `class` and not `typeof` because according to `?typeof`

> typeof determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object

```
class(bank)
```

-checking

```
> data(iris)
> typeof(iris)
[1] "list"
> class(iris)
[1] "data.frame"
> is.list(iris)
[1] TRUE
> is.data.frame(iris)
[1] TRUE
```

The reason is also that `data.frame` is a `list` with elements (`columns`) of equal length

Comment: Oh oops haha, sorry about that, I guess since it's all in quotations for some reason the values are being read non-numerically so that threw me off. Thanks!